# Vectorizing a matlab loop with internal functions

Tags: matlab, vectorization, user-defined-functions

I have a 3D Mesh grid, X, Y, Z.  I want to create a new 3D array that is a function of X, Y, & Z.  That function comprises the sum of several 3D Gaussians located at different points.  Currently, I have a for loop that runs over the different points where I have my gaussians, and I have an array of center locations r0(nGauss, 1:3)

```
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(-10:.1:10);
 Psi=0*X; 
 for index = 1:nGauss
   Psi = Psi + Gauss3D(X,Y,Z,[r0(index,1),r0(index,2),r0(index,3)]);
 end
```

where my 3D gaussian function is

```
function output=Gauss3D(X,Y,Z,r0)
    output=exp(-(X-r0(1)).^2 + (Y-r0(2)).^2 + (Z-r0(3)).^2);
 end
```

I'm happy to redesign the function, which is the slowest part of my code and has to happen many many time, but I can't figure out how to vectorize this so that it will run faster.  Any suggestions would be appreciated

*****NB the Original function had a square root in it, and has been modified to make it an actual gaussian***

Comment: I'm working on this a bit but to be honest I doubt vectorizing will do much due to the sheer calculation required. X,Y, and Z all have 8  million elements each which means that unless nGauss is below 10 you'll run out of memory almost instantly if you try to vectorize.

Comment: Are your values in `r0` positioned *exactly* at grid points in `X,Y,Z`, or could they fall between them?

Comment: Also, should you remove the `sqrt` to make it a true Gaussian, like Cris mentions below?

Comment: They can fall in between.  My grid is square, but my r0 may form a different (non-commensurate) geometry

Comment: Also, I removed the square root sign.  The actual code uses a spherically shaped exponentially decay, but I was working on a separate project when I wrote that description and accidentally called them Gaussians.  Thanks for point that out and I corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE!** I've modified your code to create a Gaussian, which was:

> ```
> output=exp(-sqrt((X-r0(1)).^2 + (Y-r0(2)).^2 + (Z-r0(3)).^2));
> ```

That does not make a Gaussian. I changed this to:

```
output = exp(-((X-r0(1)).^2 + (Y-r0(2)).^2 + (Z-r0(3)).^2));
```

(note no `sqrt`). This is a Gaussian with sigma = sqrt(1/2).

If this is not what you want, then this answer might not be very useful to you, because your function does not go to 0 as fast as the Gaussian, and therefore is harder to truncate, and it is not separable.

---

Vectorizing this code is pointless, as the other answers attest. MATLAB's JIT is perfectly capable of running this as fast as it'll go. But you can reduce the amount of computation significantly by noting that the Gaussian goes to almost zero very quickly, and is separable:

- Most of the `exp` evaluations you're doing here yield a very tiny number. You don't need to compute those, just fill in 0.
- `exp(-x.^2-y.^2)` is the same as `exp(-x.^2).*exp(-y.^2)`, which is much cheaper to compute.

Let's put these two things to the test. Here is the test code:

```
function gaussian_test

N = 100;
r0 = rand(N,3)*20 - 10;

% Original
tic
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(-10:.1:10);
Psi1 = zeros(size(X)); 
for index = 1:N
  Psi1 = Psi1 + Gauss3D(X,Y,Z,r0(index,:));
end
t = toc;
fprintf('original, time = %f\n',t)

% Fast, large truncation
tic
[X,Y,Z] = deal(-10:.1:10);
Psi2 = zeros(numel(X),numel(Y),numel(Z));
for index = 1:N
   Psi2 = Gauss3D_fast(Psi2,X,Y,Z,r0(index,:),5);
end
t = toc;
fprintf('tuncation = 5, time = %f\n',t)
fprintf('mean abs error = %f\n',mean(reshape(abs(Psi2-Psi1),[],1)))
fprintf('mean square error = %f\n',mean(reshape((Psi2-Psi1).^2,[],1)))
fprintf('max abs error = %f\n',max(reshape(abs(Psi2-Psi1),[],1)))

% Fast, smaller truncation
tic
[X,Y,Z] = deal(-10:.1:10);
Psi3 = zeros(numel(X),numel(Y),numel(Z));
for index = 1:N
   Psi3 = Gauss3D_fast(Psi3,X,Y,Z,r0(index,:),3);
end
t = toc;
fprintf('tuncation = 3, time = %f\n',t)
fprintf('mean abs error = %f\n',mean(reshape(abs(Psi3-Psi1),[],1)))
fprintf('mean square error = %f\n',mean(reshape((Psi3-Psi1).^2,[],1)))
fprintf('max abs error = %f\n',max(reshape(abs(Psi3-Psi1),[],1)))

% DIPimage, same smaller truncation
tic
Psi4 = newim(201,201,201);
coords = (r0+10) * 10;
Psi4 = gaussianblob(Psi4,coords,10*sqrt(1/2),(pi*100).^(3/2));
t = toc;
fprintf('DIPimage, time = %f\n',t)
fprintf('mean abs error = %f\n',mean(reshape(abs(Psi4-Psi1),[],1)))
fprintf('mean square error = %f\n',mean(reshape((Psi4-Psi1).^2,[],1)))
fprintf('max abs error = %f\n',max(reshape(abs(Psi4-Psi1),[],1)))

end % of function gaussian_test

function output = Gauss3D(X,Y,Z,r0)
   output = exp(-((X-r0(1)).^2 + (Y-r0(2)).^2 + (Z-r0(3)).^2));
end

function Psi = Gauss3D_fast(Psi,X,Y,Z,r0,trunc)
   % sigma = sqrt(1/2)
   x = X-r0(1);
   y = Y-r0(2);
   z = Z-r0(3);
   mx = abs(x) < trunc*sqrt(1/2);
   my = abs(y) < trunc*sqrt(1/2);
   mz = abs(z) < trunc*sqrt(1/2);
   Psi(my,mx,mz) = Psi(my,mx,mz) + exp(-x(mx).^2) .* reshape(exp(-y(my).^2),[],1) .* reshape(exp(-z(mz).^2),1,1,[]);
   % Note! the line above uses implicit singleton expansion. For older MATLABs use bsxfun
end
```

This is the output on my machine, reordered for readability (I'm still on MATLAB R2017a):

```
              |  time(s) | mean abs | mean sq. | max abs
--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------
original      | 5.035762 |          |          |         
tuncation = 5 | 0.169807 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000005
tuncation = 3 | 0.054737 | 0.000452 | 0.000002 | 0.024378
DIPimage      | 0.044099 | 0.000452 | 0.000002 | 0.024378
```

As you can see, using these two properties of the Gaussian we can reduce time from 5.0 s to 0.17 s, a 30x speedup, with hardly noticeable differences (truncating at 5*sigma). A further 3x speedup can be gained by allowing a small error. The smallest the truncation value, the faster this will go, but the larger the error will be.

I added that last method, the `gaussianblob` function from [DIPimage](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib) (I'm an author), just to show that option in case you need to squeeze that bit of extra time from your code. That function is implemented in C++. This version that I used you will need to compile yourself. Our [current official release](http://www.diplib.org/download) implements this function still in M-file code, and is not as fast.

---

Further chance of improvement is if the fractional part of the coordinates is always the same (w.r.t. the pixel grid). In this case, you can draw the Gaussian once, and shift it over to each of the centroids.

Another alternative involves computing the Gaussian once, at a somewhat larger scale, and interpolating into it to generate each of the 1D Gaussians needed to generate the output. I did not implement this, I have no idea if it will be faster or if the time difference will be significant. In the old days, `exp` was expensive, I'm not sure this is still the case.

Answer (score 1):

So, I am building off of the answer above me @Durkee. I enjoy these kinds of problems, so I thought a little about how to make each of the expansions implicit, and I have the one-line function below. Using this function I shaved .11 seconds off of the call, which is completely negligible. It looks like yours is pretty decent. The only advantage of mine might be how the code scales on a finer mesh.

```
xLin = [-10:.1:10]';
tic
psi2 = sum(exp(-sqrt((permute(xLin-r0(:,1)',[3 1 4 2])).^2 ...
    + (permute(xLin-r0(:,2)',[1 3 4 2])).^2 ...
    + (permute(xLin-r0(:,3)',[3 4 1 2])).^2)),4);
toc
```

The relative run times on my computer were (all things kept the same):

```
Original - 1.234085
Other    - 2.445375
Mine     - 1.120701
```

Comment: Darn it, you beat me to this by 5 minutes ) :

I had the code done and everything lol

Comment: Just updated it. Sorry, original post swapped an index

Comment: Yea, lol,  I imagine. Only so many ways to skin a cat :p

I ran the code on a computer with more ram. When the grid goes down to .05, I get an improvement from 2.93 ---> 2.38, which is really still pretty negligible. So, your comment really explains most of the problem

Answer (score 0):

So this is a bit of an unusual problem where on my computer the unvectorized code actually works better than the vectorized code, here is my script

```
clear
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(-10:.1:10);

Psi=0*X;
nGauss = 20; %Sample nGauss as you didn't specify
r0 = rand(nGauss,3); % Just make this up as it doesn't really matter in this case

% Your original code
tic
for index = 1:nGauss
    Psi = Psi + Gauss3D(X,Y,Z,[r0(index,1),r0(index,2),r0(index,3)]);
end
toc

% Vectorize these functions so we can use implicit broadcasting
X1 = X(:);
Y1 = Y(:);
Z1 = Z(:);
tic
val = [X1 Y1 Z1];

% Change the dimensions so that r0 operates on the right elements
r0_temp = permute(r0,[3 2 1]);

% Perform the gaussian combination
out = sum(exp(-sqrt(sum((val-r0_temp).^2,2))),3);
toc

% Check to make sure both functions match
sum(abs(vec(Psi)-vec(out)))


function output=Gauss3D(X,Y,Z,r0)
output=exp(-sqrt((X-r0(1)).^2 + (Y-r0(2)).^2 + (Z-r0(3)).^2));
end

function out = vec(in)
out = in(:);
end
```

As you can see, this is probably about as vectorized as you can get. The whole function is done using broadcasting and vectorized operations which normally improve performance ten-one hundredfold. However, in this case, this is not what we see

```
Elapsed time is 1.876460 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.909152 seconds.
```

This actually shows the unvectorized version as being faster.

There could be a few reasons for this of which I am by no means an expert.

- MATLAB uses a JIT compiler now which means that for loops are no longer inefficient.
- Your code is already reasonably vectorized, you are operating at 8 million elements at once
- Unless nGauss is 1000 or something, you're not looping through that much, and at that point, vectorization means you will run out of memory
- I could be hitting some memory threshold where I am using too much memory and that is making my code inefficient, I noticed that when I lowered the resolution on the meshgrid the vectorized version worked better

As an aside, I tested this on my GTX 1060 GPU with single precision(single precision is 10x faster than double precision on most GPUs)

```
Elapsed time is 0.087405 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.241456 seconds.
```

Once again the unvectorized version is faster, sorry I couldn't help you out but it seems that your code is about as good as you are going to get unless you lower the tolerances on your meshgrid.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, I'm using the mesh grid to then visualize a 3D function, and I can't afford to lower the resolution